# Unexpected behavior after updating a placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

The output of the following snippet

```
ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
ph += 1000
a = ph + 0
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run([a], {ph: 5}))
```

is `[5]`, and not `[1005]` as I would expected.

I've been answered that the `ph+=1000` line overwrote the original placeholder so I'm not feeding what I think I'm feeding.

However, I didn't fully understand this answer. If `ph` was a variable then the output was `[1005]` of course. So what am I feeding? What does `ph` hold after the update op?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion stems from the difference between TensorFlow variables and Python variables.

In TensorFlow, a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#placeholder) op holds no state, and there is no supported notion of "updating" it: think of it as the formal parameter to a function in other languages (e.g. `x` in `def f(x): ...` in Python). However, you can assign a `tf.placeholder()` to a *Python* variable so that you can use it elsewhere in your program.

When you write `ph += 1000`, you are creating a new tensor whose value is 1000 greater than `ph` (it is shorthand for `ph = ph + 1000`), and then assigning it to the *Python* variable `ph`. An equivalent way to write your program is:

```
ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
new_ph = ph + 1000
a = new_ph + 0
print(sess.run([a], {new_ph: 5}))
```

Note that you are actually feeding a value for the tensor `new_ph`—i.e. the *output* of the addition—so the operations that compute that addition are pruned from the graph and don't execute.